# Prevent cells from overlapping when the content is wider than the cell

Tags: fpdf

I have this.

```
for($i=0; $i < $longArreglo; $i++) {    
        $this->Cell($w[0],6, $final_array[$i][0],'LR',0,'L', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[1],6, $final_array[$i][2],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[2],6, $final_array[$i][3],'LR',0,'L', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[3],6, $final_array[$i][5],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[4],6, $final_array[$i][6],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[5],6, $final_array[$i][12],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[6],6, $final_array[$i][13],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[7],6, $final_array[$i][14],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[8],6, $final_array[$i][15],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[9],6, $final_array[$i][16],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[10],6, $final_array[$i][17],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[11],6, $final_array[$i][18],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[12],6, $final_array[$i][19],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[13],6, $final_array[$i][20],'LR',0,'C', $fill);
        $this->Ln();

    }
```

And here: `$this->Cell($w[2],6, $final_array[$i][3],'LR',0,'L', $fill);` is a person name, the width of cell is 15 and if the name is most large than cell, it does this:

[image]

I need the cells to not coalesce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post might be old but I couldn't find any other solution on the internet. I've modified Hugo's post and I hope that this will be helpful to someone one day. I've created a new method in the fpdf class for this for ease of use.

[image: PDF Example]

```
function pdfText($cellWidth, $text, $pdf){
    $textWidth = $pdf->getstringwidth($text);
    while($textWidth > $cellWidth -1){
        $text       = substr($text,0,-1);
        $textWidth  = $pdf->getstringwidth($text);
    }
    return $text;
}

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint esse quia repellat cupiditate excepturi exercitationem asperiores eligendi iusto. Blanditiis sequi suscipit assumenda quibusdam aliquid quas eligendi soluta ab fugit ad.';

$pdf->setFont('Arial', '', 10);
$cellWidth = 180;
$text = pdfText($cellWidth, $text, $pdf);
$pdf->Cell($cellWidth,6,$text,1,1,'L',0);

$pdf->setFont('Arial', '', 12);
$cellWidth = 160;
$text = pdfText($cellWidth, $text, $pdf);
$pdf->Cell($cellWidth,7,$text,1,1,'L',0);

$pdf->setFont('Arial', '', 14);
$cellWidth = 140;
$text = pdfText($cellWidth, $text, $pdf);
$pdf->Cell($cellWidth,8,$text,1,1,'L',0);

$pdf->setFont('Arial', '', 16);
$cellWidth = 120;
$text = pdfText($cellWidth, $text, $pdf);
$pdf->Cell($cellWidth,9,$text,1,1,'L',0);

$pdf->Output('I');
```

Answer (score 1):

so, the example should be:

```
// width - width of cell
// text to be put into cell
// pdf - pdf object of fpdf
// fill - how to fill cell?
function putField($width,$text,$pdf,$fill){     
 $textwidth = $pdf->getstringwidth($text); 
 while($textwidth>$width){              // loop until textwidth is shorter than cell width
  $text=substr($text,0,-1);             // strip last char
  $textwidth = $pdf->getstringwidth($text); // read text width again
 }

 $pdf->Cell($width,6, $text,'LR',0,'L', $fill); // put the cell
}

for($i=0; $i < $longArreglo; $i++) {    
   putField($w[0],$final_array[$i][0],$this,$fill);        
}
```

Comment: Modified a little to suit my needs for a different project but the only solution that I could find. Thank you.